# Perl validate module before use

Tags: perl, module

I am using Module::Pluggable to load modules from a given directory:

```
for my $module ( plugins() ) {

    eval "use $module";
    if ($@) {

        my $error = (split(/\n/, $@))[0];
        push @rplugin_errors, $error;
        print STDOUT "Failed to load $module: $error\n";
    } else {

        print STDOUT "Loaded: $module\n";
        my $mod = $module->new();
        my $module_name = $mod->{name};
        $classes{$module_name} = $mod;
    }
}
```

This function can be called via a reload method elsewhere. But if a one of the modules I am trying to "use" throws an errors it's not loaded and the script is somewhat crippled.

I'd like to validate each module in plugins() before executing use. So Ideally I could do something like:

```
$error = 0;
for my $module ( plugins() ) {

    eval TEST $module;
    if ($@) {

        print STDERR "$module failed. Will not continue";
        $error = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ($error == 0) {

    for my $module ( plugins() ) {

        use $module;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
eval TEST $module;
```

back to

```
eval "use $module";
```

Well, importing probably doesn't make sense here (or in your original code), so the following would be better:

```
eval "require $module";
```

Comment: eval "use module" will attempt to load the module not knowing if it is good or not. If it's got a syntax error it will continue to load the other and exclude the bad one. So potentially 2/3 modules have loaded. The goal is to validate them all before trying to load them. If one fails, we halt and send a message stating the reload could not take place because of a module error. I tried require but that didn't work either. :/

Comment: No, it won't continue to try to load the next one because you call `last`.

Comment: If you don't want to affect the current process, you'll have to use a different process (e.g. `system($^X, '-e', 'eval "use $ARGV; 1" or die $@', $module)`).

Comment: You can't test if a script/module (same thing) will execute/load (same thing) without actually executing it.

Comment: So then the best way is to fire off a script via the shell and see if there are errors using module::foo.

Comment: You didn't give any reason why loading the module up front would be bad, so no, I don't think that's best way. That's why I didn't put that in my answer.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, Because that doesn't allow you to compile code you've just created. You could use `eval BLOCK` if you switched to `require $path_to_module;`, but then you have to build that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating this.  Your code already includes a clause to test for errors in the `use` and report on them if any occur. (`if ($@)... print STDOUT "Failed to load $module: $error\n";`)  According to your comment on ikegami's answer, your goal is that "If one fails, we halt and send a message stating the reload could not take place because of a module error."  (Yes, I know you *said* your goal is to validate the modules before loading them.  It isn't.  Your goal is to halt if there's an error; you've just decided that pre-validation is the way to accomplish that.  This is what we call an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

You're already detecting and reporting any errors that occur...  You want to halt on error...  So, when you detect an error, halt after reporting it.

```
if ($@) {
    my $error = (split(/\n/, $@))[0];
    push @rplugin_errors, $error;
    die "Failed to load $module: $error\n";
} else {
```